# Filtering data based on value from other data frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I want to detect outliers from a data frame with grouping.
Here is the data:

```
# create 3 outliers for each group
df <- data.frame(factor = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 15),
                 value = c(rnorm(12, 10, 1), rnorm(3, 16.8, 1),
                           rnorm(12, 10.4, 1), rnorm(3, 17.6, 1),
                           rnorm(12, 9.7, 1), rnorm(3, 17.7, 1),
                           rnorm(12, 9.8, 1), rnorm(3, 17.8, 1)))
```

Using interquartile (IQR) method to determine outliers, I created a new data frame that contain "upper limit" and "lower limit" for outliers for each group.

```
quant <- group_by(df, factor) %>%
         summarise(q25 = quantile(value, 0.25),
                   q75 = quantile(value, 0.75),
                   iqr = IQR(value),
                   up = q75 + 1.5*iqr,
                   low = q25 - 1.5*iqr)
```

I would like to filter df data frame using value from quant to determine what data points count as outliers. For example, group A in df should be filtered based on value of "up" and "low" from group A in quant. Here is *the rough idea* of what I want to do (however, this code doesn't work as intended).

```
# detect outliers
df %>% group_by(factor) %>% filter(value > quant$up | value < quant$low)

# remove outliers
df %>% group_by(factor) %>% filter(value < quant$up & value > quant$low)
```

Comment: A filtering join (`dplyr::semi_join` or `dplyr::anti_join`) may be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend starting by joining the two data frames together:

```r
output = df %>%
  left_join(quant, by = "factor")
```

You can then filter as required:

```r
output %>%
  mutate(is_outlier = value > up | value < low) %>%
  filter(!is_outlier)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. I didn't aware there is left_join() function that is very convenient. I should learning more.